# When do you Set Price and Description of App before uploading to app store?

Tags: iphone, xcode

My app is very nearly complete and Ive found a very detailed tutorial online about how to go about publishing your completed app to the App Store. However it doesn't cover setting the price to charge for the app, or where you set the description for the app.. Does anyone know at what stage of the process this comes at?

Believe it or not no searching has found an answer to this question as simple as it may sound.

Thanks, Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iTunes Connect once you have created the app there is a button for "Rights and Pricing" (I think).

Anyway, it's all done in there.

Getting screen shot now.

In the app...

[image]

Then in there you get...

[image]

Comment: ahh fantastic stuff thanks very much. Any idea about the description?

Comment: @user3641747 That's all done in iTunes Connect too. You enter the App Store name, meta data, key words, description, age rating info, copyright info, etc...

Comment: ok great thanks again! Would give you a vote up but not enough rep! :(

Comment: @user3641747 no worries. You can still accept the answer though.